# Is there a way to access the "chunk" in a worker process in a pool?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, pool

I'm using the [multiprocessing pool](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) in python 3.6.

Say I'm in a worker process and I want to cache something(e.g., resource loaded from a website) of each tasks in the "chunk".

It'll be nice if I can cache them all at once for the "chunks" before I deal with individual task.

So is there a way to access the "chunks"?

All of those proccessing `func` for the [*map](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing.pool) functions deal with individual task. I've not yet seen any way to access the chunk itself.

Comment: Being **in a worker process** of the pool allows to access a **chunk**

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, how? Would you please post an anwser so I can accept?

Comment: Each worker (target function) accepts a chunk as a parameter

Comment: No it does not. The target function, ie., the `func` in `map(func, iterable[, chunksize])`,  accepts individual task instead of chunk as a parameter.

Comment: You are perceiving it in wrong way.